# How to get the correct path to reach a html-file in Xamarin.Forms.iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, path, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have created a html-file that I am now trying to reach but I am getting in a bit of trouble. The code currently looks like this when I have the `YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html` file in my iOS-map:

```
const string HTMLTemplatePath = @"YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html"; 

string path = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, HTMLTemplatePath);
```

When I try to create the path above I get a crash with the following error message:

`Could not find a part of the path "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/252DA-6758-4650-88E0-F30‌​043043/myProject.iOS‌​.app/YTPlayer‌​View-iframe-player.h‌​tml"`

How do I need to adjust in order to make this work? Do I need to move the html-file elsewhere (maybe in the shared (project) folder?) or do i need to adjust the HTMLTemplatePath-string?

This is how the html-file looks:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
 body { margin: 0; width:100%%; height:100%%; }
 html { width:100%%; height:100%%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script>
var player;
YT.ready(function() {
  player = new YT.Player('player', %%jsontemp%%);
  window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onYouTubeIframeAPIReady';
});
function onReady(event) {
    window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onReady?data=' + event.data;
}
function onStateChange(event) {
    window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onStateChange?data=' + event.data;
}
function onPlaybackQualityChange(event) {
    window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onPlaybackQualityChange?data=' + event.data;
}
function onPlayerError(event) {
    window.location.href = 'ytplayer://onError?data=' + event.data;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is that file located in your project?  Do you have it's build-action set to Content?

Comment: It is in my iOS folder right now. Where do I find "build-action"? Is it under "iOS build"?

Comment: Right click on the file in the solution explorer/pad.

Comment: Ok! I set it to content now. Let's try it!

Comment: Worked very well it seems like :) I get another error now which is progress! Thanks a lot